# flutter initState() vs build()?

Tags: flutter, state

I am confused about when to put my code in `initState()` compared to `build()` in a stateful widget. I am doing a quiz on flutter's udacity course which has [this](https://github.com/flutter/udacity-course/blob/master/course/05_stateful_widgets/task_05_stateful_widgets/lib/category_route.dart#L70) todo item, which was to move a block of code from `build()` to `initState()`. But I don't know the purpose or advantage of doing that. Why not just put all the code in `build()`?

Is it that `build()` is called only once while `initState()` is called on every state change?

Thank you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is actually the opposite.

`build` can be called again in many situations. Such as state change or parent rebuild.

While `initState` is called only one time.

`build` should be used only for layout. While `initState` is usually used for variable initialization.

Comment: so if we initialized a list by initstate and want to update some elements of that list, how will we do that? Will we call setstate from inside the build to make those changes appear in our ui

Comment: @SanjaySingh use `didUpdateWidget` or `didChangeDependencies`

Comment: I didn't used either. I just made it up to know what will happen or what to do in cases when i used initstate to initalize my variable and now want to make changes in the list and make then appear in the ui

Answer (score 7):

It's in the comment within the build state of the [link](https://github.com/flutter/udacity-course/blob/master/course/05_stateful_widgets/task_05_stateful_widgets/lib/category_route.dart#L70) you provided.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: Instead of re-creating a list of Categories in every build(),
    // save this as a variable inside the State object and create
    // the list at initialization (in initState()).
    // This way, you also don't have to pass in the list of categories to
    // _buildCategoryWidgets()
     final categories = <Category>[];  
     ...
```

Creating Categories List in the Build State will lead to the list being created on every build. This is necessary since you only want it to be created once, so the best place to do this is in initState() since it will only be called once when the state object is created, Thereby eliminating the cost of re-creating the categories on each build.

According to flutter doc:
**InitState**

> Called when this object is inserted into the tree.
>   The framework will call this method exactly once for each State object it creates.
>   Override this method to perform initialization that depends on the location at which this object was inserted into the tree (i.e., context) or on the widget used to configure this object (i.e., widget)

**build**

> The framework calls this method in a number of different situations:
>   After calling initState.
>   After calling didUpdateWidget.
>   After receiving a call to setState.
>   After a dependency of this State object changes (e.g., an InheritedWidget referenced by the previous build changes).

Comment: so if we initialized a list by initstate and want to update some elements of that list, how will we do that? Will we call setstate from inside the build to make those changes appear in our ui?